# Is this correct XML formatting for PHP parsing?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

Is the following format correct for XML? I am trying to parse the file in PHP using `simplexml_load_file` but keep receiving an error stating that there is 'Extra content at the end of the document on line 3'.

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <title>Test File</title>
  <data>
    <record id="1">
      <department>
        <name>ACME</name>
        <number>5</number>
      </dep_name>
      <floor>
        <name>ACME Floor</name>
        <number>5</number>
      </floor>
    </record>
  </data>
```

Comment: You open a `<department>` but close a `</dep_name>`

Comment: Aww, don't modify the OP, it'll confuse the rest of the readers, and googlers that have the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An XML document **must** consist of a single root element and its descendants.

Your first start tag is `<title>`. It has a text node as its sole descendent. You then have a `</title>` tag which ends the root element and thus the document.

`<data>` and everything following it is therefore an error.

You probably want to create a new element type to be the root (and wrap the entire document, excluding the XML declaration, with it).

You also need to correct either `<department>` or `</dep_name>` as you appear to have changed the name of the element halfway through creating it.

You should run your code through [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/) or a [lint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html), as that will highlight errors.

Comment: Ah ok, so in this case as long as I create a new tag which encapsulates `<title>` and `<data>` then it will be able to parse correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by "You probably want to create a new element type to be the root."

Answer (score 2):

you need to have a root for your structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
    <title>Test File</title>
    <data>
        <record id="1">
            <department>
                <name>ACME</name>
                <number>5</number>
            </department>
            <floor>
                <name>ACME Floor</name>
                <number>5</number>
            </floor>
        </record>
    </data>
</xml>
```

or else your XML parser will think that your root is `<title>` and that with in it all your information is contained.

Also, `<department>` needs to be closed by `</department>`, which has been reflected in my answer.